# change php regex to js regex **text**

Tags: javascript, php, regex

With this function I bold the text between `**text**`

```
function bold_text($string) {
    return preg_replace('#\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}#', '<strong>$1</strong>', $string);
}
```

Now I need to change it to js

```
function bold_text() {
    return preg_replace('#\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}#', '<strong>$1</strong>', string);
}
```

I tried something like `var string=string.bold_text()` but its not working

How do I change get bold text by using js?

Comment: have you read the docs? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I need th js version of this regex `'#\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const regex = /\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/gm;
const str = `How **are** you Dan?`;
const subst = `<strong>$1</strong>`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
document.write(result);
```

**Using Function:**

```js
function bold_text(string) {
  const regex = /\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/gm;
  const subst = `<strong>$1</strong>`;
  const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
  return result;
}

const str = `How **are** you Dan?`;
document.write(bold_text(str));
```

Comment: terrific. Do the regex var need to be between quotes?

Comment: no without quotes it should work. see my edit

Comment: it works. thank you +1!

Comment: @Dan glad it works you for. Best of luck :)